# Centering dropdown menu using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center my dropdown menu in Bootstap.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

It pulls to the left by default, or I could use `pull-right` defined as follows to make it go to the right:

```
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

I want to center it though. I'm new to Boostrap and can't figure out how to center it. Any tips? I tried right:50% but that didn't work.

Note: I'm not looking to center the actual text in the dropdown menu. I'm looking to center the actual dropdown menu and carret under the navigation menu item that it drops down from.

Here is my full code snippet in my template:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="tab_profile">
        <a href="{% url profile_detail user.username %}">{% trans "PROFILE" %}</a>
    </li>
    <li id="product_data">
        <a href="{% url all_models %}">{% trans "PRODUCT DATA" %}</a>
    </li>
    <li id="product_library">
        <a href="{% url library %}">{% trans "LIBRARY" %}</a>
    </li>
  <li id="database">
        <a href="/DATABASE/">{% trans "DATABASE" %}</a>
    </li>
        <li class="dropdown" id = "community">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">COMMUNITY</a> 
             <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li> <a href="/profiles">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="/questions/">Questions and Answers</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url view_requests %}">Requests</a></li>
              </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 1px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
.dropdown-menu {
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -70px;
}
```

This worked for me when using a default bootstrap drop down menu. Just adjust the margin-left depending on how wide your menu is.

Comment: wouldn't using a px value would make it only work for dropdown-menu of a specific size?

Answer (score 2):

You can add below as CSS and give this class in  tag as shown below.

```
.centerDropdown {
    left: auto !important;
    right: -25% !important;
}
.centerDropdown:after {
   left: auto !important;
   right: 45% !important;
}
```

In HTML Code,

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="/channel/list" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
           Lists
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu centerDropdown">
          <li><a href="/list">Find a list</a></li>
          <li><a href="/my">My lists</a></li>
          <li><a href="/create">Create a list</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: I'm curious what kind of positioning you have on the parent elements of that snippet?  I tried in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/i83GXoup85dLpIWcKUQJ with no success...

Answer (score 1):

This response a bit late, but hopefully will be useful. To center a Bootstrap dropdown menu with regard to its parent, try this.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    left: -40px;
    right: -40px;
}
```

Adjust size as needed, just make sure the number values (40px in this example) match each other. Here, this pulls the left and right sides of the dropdown menu 40px to the left and 40px to the right of the parental/originating link, respectively.

BONUS ROUND:
In the event a list item's text extends wider than the menu, consider adding the following declaration.

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    white-space: normal;
}
```