# alignment for twitter bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a bootstrap navbar with dropdown menu

http://jsfiddle.net/yabasha/fex8N/3/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
display: block;    
}
```

Is there a way to change the default alignment for the dropdown-menu (from left to center / right) so the arrow would display in center / right?

Comment: link to JSFiddle is broken, shows 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSfiddle with your example http://jsfiddle.net/shail/fex8N/5/

change the following code to your liking to center the drop down caret :

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {

left: 83px;  /change to your liking/

 }
 .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {

left: 83px;  /keep values in after and before same /

   }
```

To align the li elements to the right side :

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
             text-align:right;
   }
```

To align the li elements to the center :

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
             text-align:center;
   }
```

Comment: jsfiddle link is now a 404

Answer (score 16):

It's better to avoid the use of `px` for positioning, since the dropdown´s width may change. This would be more appropriate for centering the caret:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.pull-center:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.pull-center:before {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
}
```

For right alignment, you just need to add the class `pull-right` to the dropdown:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Link</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <!-- your menu -->
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in my project and have answered in below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21849528/2026261.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 150px; text-align: right;">
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Write Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Posts List</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
     </ul>
     <label class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Welcome Hero</label>
     <span class="caret" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
  </div>
```

In this way you can align menu to left or right according to your choice.[image]