# Left bootstrap dropdown-toggle button?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wonder if there exists or if there is a way to make a bootstrap button like the one [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup), but with the dropdown-toggle to the left. If I just alter the order in the html, then the buttons do show in correct order, but their surfaces do not "snap" right to be totally adjacent as a unified button entity.

Comment: @pregmatch: What exactly you do not understand? The question I think is clear. Instead of having the toggle in the link provided to the right is it possible to have it to the left? You can check the code and the result on the link provided in the post.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115204/alignment-for-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu

Comment: @Resber: The link to the fiddle is broken in the accepted answer, however I would guess that this is not what I am looking for, since I am looking to place to the left the `dropdown-toggle` button. In the link provided in my SO question the bootstrap button consists of two buttons adjacent one after the other... Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: How can I undo a flag? By mistake I flagged Resbers comment which is absolutely fine... How can I undo it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to accomplish?

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/2mbsLkmw/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group btn-group-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>

    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add btn-group-left to the btn-group div.

The add this css to override bootstrap:

**CSS:**

```
.btn-group.btn-group-left .dropdown-toggle {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
}
.btn-group.btn-group-left .dropdown-toggle+.btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeap... I was looking for exactly this. Thanks!